# Gnome Terminal won't autocomplete

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

My gnome-terminal on a ubuntu 10.10 machine is not working the way it should work. No autocomplete is working. `ctrl + l` won't clear the screen, bash prompt is simply a `$` and nothing else. I got this machine passed on from someone else. I just created a new user for myself and hoped that I would get a fresh start.

I checked and there is no `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`. There was a folder named `.profile.d` that I renamed to something else. Stil the problem persists.

There are no configuration files inside my home directory either (.bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_aliases)

Comment: Sounds like you are running `sh` instead of `bash`.  Try a `ps $$` to confirm.

Comment: yes ! it says `sh`. I remember I should specify what would be my login shell but dont remember where. Usermod should do the trick ?

Comment: `chsh` if you have that.

Comment: @Mat usermod worked for me .. didnt try chsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure that you are indeed running bash and not another csh for example by executing the following:

```
ps -p $$
```

This will tell you what shell you are running.
If this returns something different than bash you can try your shortcuts after running the following:

```
bash
```

You can also change the users shell by running:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash `whoami`
```